# iphone app background image stretched in 3.5 simulator

Tags: ios

I am creating an app with a single view. The app has a background image. In my code I use:

```
#define deviceIsIPhone5 ([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.height == 568 ? YES : NO)
```

Then in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
if (deviceIsIPhone5)
{
    backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-568h.png"];
}
else
{
    backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];
}
```

`Background.png` is 640x960

`Background-658h.png` is 640x1136

Works fine with 4" simulator but when I use 3.5" simulator the bottom of the picture is cut out, as if it is being stretched...

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Is it entering the `else`?  Is backgroundImage, whatever it is, set up with autolayout to only take up the visible screen?

Comment: Yes, it is entering the else. I tried with NSLog. Autolayout can't be set on an image view but it is set on the view controller... The Image View is set to fill up the controller in the storyboard.

Comment: NSLog the backgroundImage object after this section of code.  It should tell you its frame.

Comment: Is this what you meant?

 Image :  <UIImageView: 0x8dcc870; frame = (0 0; 320 568); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8dcc930>> 

Used:     NSLog(@"Image :  %@ ", backgroundImage );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, NSLog is indicating that the size of the ImageView's frame extends below the bottom of the screen.

The reported frame of the image view is:

```
(0 0; 320 568)
```

The image looks stretched because it is being stretched to fill a frame extending off the screen.  You need to make sure your image view is sized appropriately depending on the screen size.

Comment: A quick thing if you don't mind. What should the image view mode be set to to achieve the best results here? I tried scale to fill, aspect fit and fill but all still display it cut down. Scale to fill cuts down the bottom still. My frame now shows the correct 320 by 480...

Comment: If your image is the right size, content mode shouldn't matter, but personally, I tend to default to Aspect Fit.

Answer (score 0):

Set autoresing mask of your image view as shown in figure.
[image]